# Another relation between the cosine and Dirac's delta function

Tags: fourier-transform, dirac-delta

I am looking for a smooth function $f_\sigma(x)$ with parameter $\sigma \in [0,1]$, such that

$$\lim_{\sigma \rightarrow 1}\ f_\sigma(x) = \cos(\pi x)$$

and

$$\lim_{\sigma \rightarrow 0}\  f_\sigma(x) = \sum_{i = -\infty}^{\infty}(-1)^i\ \delta(x-i) =: D(x)$$

i.e. a series of alternating delta peaks, superelevating the peaks of the cosine.

The relation between cosine and Dirac's delta function $\delta$ was given by [Fourier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#History):

$$\delta(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\ dp\ \cos(px)$$

You can also consider $\delta$ as the [limit](http://hitoshi.berkeley.edu/221a/delta.pdf)

$$\delta(x) = \lim_{\sigma \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} e^{-x^2/2\sigma^2}$$

Given this definition of $\delta$ there is a straight-forward and somehow "trivial" solution:

$$f_\sigma(x) = \sigma\cos(\pi x) + (1-\sigma)\sum_{i = -\infty}^{\infty}(-1)^i\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} e^{-(x-i)^2/2\sigma^2}$$

Question 1: Is there a more "simple", "natural" family of functions $f_\sigma(x)$, esp. without infinite sums?

Question 2: What is the Fourier transform of $D(x)$?

Comment: It might be useful to elaborate on why do you need this function

Comment: I am wondering what the Fourier transform of a long regular sequence of spikes - e.g. action potentials in a biological neuron - might be (which is a somehow periodic function).

Comment: Hans Stricker, if you define your spikers in terms of delta function, then your definition is precise enough to lead to one and only one Fourier series representation

Comment: Without having been aware of this before: there seems to be a strong interrelation between Gaussian functions, neural networks, and function approximation: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function

Answer (score 1):

Take $\varphi(x) = e^{-\pi x^2}$ or any function you like

Let $$\psi_\alpha(x) = \frac{1}{\alpha }\sum_n (-1)^n \varphi( (x- n)/\alpha)$$ 
 $$F_\alpha(x) = (1-\alpha)\psi_\alpha(x) +\alpha \cos(\pi x), \qquad\qquad f_\sigma = F_{\displaystyle e^{-\sigma}}$$

Comment: Given my original question this seems to be a correct answer. Sorry for having edited my question in the meanwhile (to exclude this straight-forward answer).

Comment: @HansStricker I don't see what you mean with "no infinite sum".  Also why don't you look at $\frac{1}{C_{2n+1}}\cos(\pi x)^{2n+1}$ where $C_{2n+1} = \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \cos(\pi x)^{2n+1}dx$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @reuns' request (what I mean with "no infinite sum") I could clarify what I mean, and this is what I came up with: The infinite sum is only necessary to make the function periodical. But the function is a periodical repetition of one half-period $f_\sigma(x)$, $x \in [0,1]$ which is "simple" and "natural":

[image]

$$f_\sigma(x) = \sigma\cos(\pi x) + \frac{1-\sigma}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} (e^{-x^2/2\sigma^2} - e^{-(x-1)^2/2\sigma^2})$$

with $f_\sigma(0.5) \equiv 0$. (Obviously, considering only the quarter-period $[0,0.5]$ would suffice.)

The quest for the Fourier transform of $D(x)$ (see original question) remains open, i.e. for the most "simple" presentation – the presentations of the Fourier transforms of the cosine and Dirac's delta function being examples of being "simple" (resp. "trivial").